# Get data from array of object and put it to key value

Tags: javascript

I want to take `that._mCon.usa` which have array of object's and put the data like key value 
in _mUsa object,In the object instance I've name and path ,I try like following and its not working the _mUsa is not filled with data...any idea what im doing wrong here ?

```
_mUsa{

},

for(var i = 0; i <= that._mCon.usa.length; i++) {

that._mUsa[that._mCon.usa[i][name]] = that._mUsa[that._mCon.usa[i][path]];

}
```

this is that._mCon.usa with the name and path properties

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Object properties are accessed using `.propertyname`, so it should be:

```
that._mUsa[that._mCon.usa[i].name] = that._mUsa[that._mCon.usa[i].path];
```

You use `[name]` when the property name is dynamic, and `name` is a variable containing the property name.

You can use `[]` with a literal string, e.g. `['name']` and `['path']`, but there's little point to that; if the property is known, just use the normal dot notation.

Comment: Thanks just one clarification,what do you mean by  if the property is known use dot notation?if you use ['name'] the property is also known...

Comment: dot notation is what I showed in the first part of the answer, with a dot before `name`.

Comment: This is basic Javascript syntax, isn't it?

Comment: Correct I understand it but I refer to your last statement,not sure that I got it ...

Comment: `['name']` is bracket notation, `.name` is dot notation. The latter is the normal way to access object properties when the property name is static.